Publishing MySQL-8 data in GeoServer, the latitude and longitude are fliped
When I publish geom data from MySQL-8, GeoServer retrieves the Bounding Boxes with X and Y positions incorrectly. The longitude range appears in Y, and the latitude range appears in X. This happens because MySQL-8 stores geometry data with the coordinate order as [latitude, longitude], whereas GeoServer expects the order to be [longitude, latitude]. Is there any way to resolve this coordinate order issue?

If I use SELECT ST_SwapXY(geom) FROM t_data_asset_range, it will result in an error


Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for asset_data
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:536)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:434)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:364)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureSource.getBounds(GeoServerFeatureSource.java:625)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:568)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:551)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.BasicResourceConfig$1.onSubmit(BasicResourceConfig.java:158)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:787)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:174)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for asset_data
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1347)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:530)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: A parameter of function st_srid contains a geometry with latitude 113.201093, which is out of range. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1201)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1322)



If you use an SQL view, applying ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(ST_SwapXY(geom))) during publication can achieve a coordinate order of [longitude, latitude].

In this case, when GeoServer displays the WMS service, it cannot leverage spatial indexes to efficiently query data stored in MySQL. This limitation can significantly impact the performance of spatial analysis and retrieval operations. Spatial indexes are crucial for optimizing queries that involve geographic data, as they reduce the amount of data that needs to be scanned during a query 20
. Without proper indexing, every request might require a full table scan, which is inefficient especially with large datasets.Are there any better methods available?

I notice that the MySQL driver has been updated recently (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/pull/8088) so it may be worth upgrade to a recent nightly build and seeing if that fixes the issue.

I have come up with a solution. By customizing a new coordinate system in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS table in MySQL 8, and setting the axis order to AXIS["Longitude", EAST], AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], this issue can be resolved.

thank you for your answer，it is really helpful！
